# How to hide NavigationView when push to another Screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have 2 screens CourseList and second CourseDetail. where I'm able to hide navigationView on First/Initial Screen by blow code.

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView  {
        List (networkManager.courses)  { course in
            NavigationLink(destination: CourseDetails(course: course)) {
                CourseRow(course: course)
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Courses"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(true) //It Hides NavigationView

    }
}
```

On Second Screen Course Detail I want to hide Navigationbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your CourseDetails view:

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Sometimes you first need to set the title to be able to hide the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

You try with this code :

```
struct SecondScreen: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        BottomView()
            .offset(y: 90)
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarTitle("")
}}
```